# how to manage two keyboard event handler for one object

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had to use both keypress and keydown handler for one html element.But both keypress and keydown are triggered (as it is expected though).As a result i get two string in my contend div when i press one key.

**.only keydown not allowing me to copy a continuous string by like 'aaaaaaa' which i have achieved by holding the 'a' button into my 'content' div . I need two handler because,if i press and hold on to a key i get single letter in my content div,not a array of letters.That' why i need the keypress handler here**.But i really need to stop one when other is active.How it can be done.Or if there are other better way around to do it,please let me know

```js
var editor=document.getElementById('editor');
var content=document.getElementById('content');
editor.addEventListener('keypress',function(e){
  
   addText(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
   
});
editor.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
         
  
   addText(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
      
   
});
function addText(words){
  content.innerHTML=content.innerHTML+words;
  }
```

```css
#content{
      width:500px;
   height:auto;
   
   }
      #editor{
      position:relative;
      width:400px;
   height:200px;
   border:1px solid black;
   word-wrap: break-word;
   padding-left:4px;
   padding-right:4px;
   padding-bottom:1em;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   overflow:scroll;
   }
```

```html
<div id='editor' contenteditable='true' ></div>
<div id='content'></div>
```

Comment: I didn't get it, why did you need both events ?

Comment: i mentioned it in bold letters...only keydown not allowing me to copy a continuous string by like 'aaaaaaa' which i have achieved by holding 'a' button into my 'content' div

Comment: And I read that, but why wouldn't just the `keydown` event work, or even better, the `input` event ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vj8102kL/

Comment: @adeneo i cant transfer the letters to my addText function as e.keycode or e.which won't work with input event..

Comment: And generally you're better of just transfering the entire text, instead of converting keycodes. Is there a really good reason for using `fromCharCode` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyup function instead of keypress and keydown.

Comment: if i use keyup only i cant copy a continuous string like 'aaaaaaa' into my content div, which i can if use keypress .i hope i made u understand